# I can't seem to round values with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting a ton of decimal places for my values on the y-axis when I ggplot something using a command like this:

```
x <- c(39.029998779296875000, 39.080001831054687500, 38.990001678466796875, 39.000000000000000000, 38.990001678466796875)
example <- data.frame(i=1:5, X=x)
ggplot(example, aes(i, y=foo, color=variable)) + geom_line(aes(y=X, color='X'))
```

What is the appropiate way to tell ggplot to adjust the values to not have that many decimal places?

Here is my output from this command:

[image: This image is the output!]

Here is the output of `sessionInfo()` - nothing looks fishy here to me:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] grid      grDevices graphics  stats     datasets  utils     methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-17        RColorBrewer_1.0-5 colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       memoise_0.1        munsell_0.3        plyr_1.7.1     \

 [9] proto_0.3-9.2      reshape2_1.2.1     scales_0.2.0       stringr_0.6        tools_2.15.0
```

Comment: Code. Not. Reproducible.

Comment: Not the first (or even the second) time this questioner has been advised to make questions reproducible.

Comment: edited to have only reproducible code

Comment: I see only 2 decimal places with the edited code as well.

Comment: The above is an image of the output I see when I run the above. I see much more than 2 decimal places. Even if I say 'options(digits=4)' or something.

Comment: You might have to share the output of `sessionInfo()` to help people narrow things down. It might also be a good idea to try running the code in your question in a fresh R session and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I'm only seeing 2 digits to the right of the decimal in a Mac running 2.15.2.

Comment: You R version is not up-to-date and neither is your version of ggplot2.

Comment: Oh so this is a version bug? very surprised even at 2.15.0 this would be the case.

Comment: Hard to tell whether it is a bug in R or in ggplot2. I would guess the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an issue with your `digits` option. I can reproduce if I set `options(digits=22)`, rather than use the factory default of `7`, which gives only 2 digits after the decimal points with this data:

```
print(x,digits=7)
[1] 39.03 39.08 38.99 39.00 38.99
```

So, try restoring it with:

```
options(digits=7)
```

Comment: In an earlier edit of the q @PalaceChen claimed that setting `options(digits = 3)` didn't fix the problem, but I strongly suspect that they may simply have been confused and thought they reset it when in fact they hadn't.

Comment: This was correct! I am very surprised. My .Rprofile had options(digits=19) and even though inside the R session I called options(digits=3) or options(digits=5) it didn't seem to change it. I'm curious why this override doesnt take place once I open the R session? I had to do it in the .Rprofile for it to work